# Making a US Heat Map?

Tags: python, pandas, heatmap, kaggle

'''

```
perstate = df[df['State'] != '']['State'].value_counts().to_dict()
data = [dict(
        type = 'choropleth',
        autocolorscale = False,
        colorscale = 'Blues',
        reversescale = True,
        locations = list(perstate.keys()),
        locationmode = 'USA-states',
        text = list(perstate.values()),
        z = list(perstate.values()),
        marker = dict(
            line = dict(
                color = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                width = 2)
            ),
        )]

layout = dict(
         title = 'Bachelor contestants by State',
         geo = dict(
             scope = 'usa',
             projection = dict(type = 'albers usa'),
             countrycolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
             showlakes = True,
             lakecolor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)')
         )

figure = dict(data = data, layout = layout)
iplot(figure)
```

'''

This is giving me the following:
    TypeError
    Traceback (most recent call last)

```
<ipython-input-294-8cdc028c4fa9> in <module>
      7         colorscale = 'Blues',
      8         reversescale = True,
----> 9         locations = list(perstate.keys()),
     10         locationmode = 'USA-states',
     11         text = list(perstate.values()),

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

It was working earlier today and I haven't changed anything. Why could this be happening? I am using a notebook in Kaggle. I am trying to take the column 'State' which has the states abbreviations and I want to make a heat map.

Comment: Could you give the whole error, including the line number, as it is currently unproducible due to the nature of this problem. Most likely, you have a list e.g. a list named xyz and you are doing xyz(), which is not possible as the list is not a function. Perhaps you have variable names overlapping with function names.

Comment: @RealPawPaw Just edited so it shows the whole error! Thank you

Comment: Do you have a variable named called 'list'?

Comment: @RealPawPaw I do not, I thought that would be necessary for the heatmap

Comment: @ElitDogu Is the solution by RealPawPaw correct?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error, it is most likely that you have redefined the name `list` to a variable name, so that when you call `list()` to cast a variable to a type of `list`, the Python interpreter is actually trying to call your redefined variable as a function.

Example:

```
print(list("123")) # prints ["1", "2", "3"]
```

Now, if you define a variable called `list`, this happens:

```
list = ["redefining", "list"]
print(list("123")) # TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Python thinks you've tried to call a variable as a function!

To resolve this issue, simply rename `list` to another name. The full code hasn't been posted, but you've likely redefined `list` at least somewhere.